# parse csv file, ignoring comma held in quotes c#

Tags: c#, parsing, csv, textfieldparser

I am currently looking at splitting a CSV file that is read into an application by the comma, however, there is legitimate comma's held in double quotes that are getting split when i dont want them to be.

when using TextFieldParser this is reading the fields that I am wanting it to read, however its reading all the fields and then i am struggling to get them out on the correct lines.

```
 public string ParseCSVForFields(string dataFileName)
    {

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var line = new List<string>();
        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(dataFileName))
        {
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");
            parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                //Processing row
                string currentRow = parser.ReadLine();
                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                foreach (var field in fields)
                {
                //    this is where i am stuck
                }



            }

        }

        return null;

    }
```

any and all help would be very much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Do it yourself? Or go and use filehelpers http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/

Comment: the HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes means that your values and enclosed in quotes like: "val,val2,val3","val4" then the parser will return "val,val2,val4" | "val4"

Comment: I don't understand the problem from current description. Could you please provide example input, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: The problem is that a CSV file that contains two fields like "a","13,21" is not really delimited by a comma . The example code will see three fields and not two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling both `ReadLine` and `ReadFields`. That seems suspicious. Remove the `ReadLine` part.

Comment: in addition to this i was also missing

parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;